I'm having trouble connecting to server with Remote Desktop Connection
A screenshot explains it better. I can't connect because of this. My Remote Desktop Connection fails because the remote computer can't be authenticated due to problems with its security certificate. It says it's a name mismatch. The name on the certificate is GNOME. I assume I need to change this either to the IP address or the name of the server but I'm not sure where I would do this.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with an XFCE Desktop

Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Ubuntu 22.04 with an XFCE Desktop
